# Flipped box with tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

In the second box I tried to imitate the layout of the first box but with the title down. Obviously, the result is not correct. In fact, the result that I foresee is in the third box; but I do not know how to implement it using the `tcolorbox` features.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\tcbset{%
    myboxmainstyle/.style={%
        enhanced,
        segmentation style={solid,line width=1pt,decorate,decoration={zigzag}},
        center title,
        halign=flush center,
        boxrule=1pt,
        arc is angular, arc=3pt,
    }
}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
    adjusted title={#2},
    myboxmainstyle,
    #1,
}

\usepackage{environ}

\newcommand\myrotateboxgrap[1]{\reflectbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{#1}}}
\newcommand\myrotateboxtikz[1]{\tikz[baseline=(box.north)]\node[yscale=-1,inner sep=0,outer sep=0](box){#1};}

\NewEnviron{myboxflipped}[2][]{%
    %\myrotateboxgrap{\begin{mybox}[#1]{\myrotateboxgrap{#2}}\myrotateboxgrap{\BODY}\end{mybox}}
    \myrotateboxtikz{\begin{mybox}[#1]{\myrotateboxtikz{#2}}\myrotateboxtikz{\BODY}\end{mybox}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{mybox}[]{Test}
        bla bla
    \end{mybox}
    \begin{mybox}[attach boxed title to bottom center={yshift=0.25mm+\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=-2mm+\tcboxedtitleheight/2}]{Test}
        bla bla
    \end{mybox}
    \begin{myboxflipped}[colback=pink]{Test}
        bla bla
    \end{myboxflipped}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are those `\NewEnviron` stuff commands really necessary?

Comment: I want to flip the box frame, but not its contents.

Comment: Well, you want to reverse the position of the box and the title, with other words

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `tcolorbox` manual has an example `flipbox` which does precisely this flipping of the box and title (See page 161 as of version 4.15).

The crucial point is `minipage boxed title*` which expands the boxed title the width of outer `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\tcbset{%
    myboxmainstyle/.style={%
      enhanced,
      segmentation style={solid,line width=1pt,decorate,decoration={zigzag}},
      center title,
      halign=flush center,
      boxrule=1pt,
      arc is angular, arc=3pt,
    }
}


\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{
  enhanced,
  sharp corners=south,
  myboxmainstyle,
  attach boxed title to bottom center={yshift=0.5mm},
  minipage boxed title*,
  boxed title style={enhanced,
    size=normal,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    %interior hidden,
    sharp corners=north,
    boxrule=1pt,
    colback=red,
    arc is angular, arc=3pt},
  title={#2},#1
}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{mybox}[]{Test}
        bla bla
    \end{mybox}
    \begin{mybox}[colback={yellow},coltitle=black,colbacktitle=red]{Another Test}
        bla bla
    \end{mybox}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\tcbset{%
    myboxmainstyle/.style={%
      enhanced,
      segmentation style={solid,line width=1pt,decorate,decoration={zigzag}},
      center title,
      halign=flush center,
      boxrule=1pt,
      arc is angular, arc=3pt,
    }
}


\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{
  enhanced,
  sharp corners=south,
  myboxmainstyle,
  attach boxed title to bottom center={yshift=0.5mm},
  minipage boxed title*,
  boxed title style={enhanced,
    size=normal,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    center title,
    sharp corners=north,
    boxrule=1pt,
    arc is angular, arc=3pt},
  title={{\centering #2}},#1
}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{mybox}[]{Test}
        bla bla
    \end{mybox}
    \begin{mybox}[colback={yellow},coltitle=black,colbacktitle=red]{Another Test}
        bla bla
    \end{mybox}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you point me the page? I am using TexLive 2015.

Comment: @cacamailg: Page 144 of the current version 3.80, at the lower part of that  page

Comment: For me it seems centered :-).

Comment: @cacamailg: Yes, I've updated. -- `\centering #2` helps.

Comment: I noticed a problem width shadows :(. If you add `drop fuzzy shadow
` to the style, it will not look nice.

Comment: @cacamailg: How many shadows did your box have initially? None! That's not in the original question